Why doesn't a component style apply to a dynamically inserted element?
I am programmatically appending a new element to an existing element in my component, but the styles associated with the .target class defined in the component's styles do not appear to apply to the new element. Why are the styles not applied?
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, inject, viewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div #container>
      <div class="target">Pre-existing .target element</div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: `
    .target {
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
  `,
})
export class FooComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  private readonly container = viewChild.required<ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>>('container');

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.container().nativeElement) {
      const target = document.createElement('div');
      target.innerText = 'Dynamic .target element';
      target.classList.add('target');
      this.container().nativeElement.appendChild(target);
    }
  }
}



Dynamically inserted elements might not inherit component styles due to view encapsulation, Renderer2 limitations, or CSS specificity issues. To apply styles successfully, you may need to disable encapsulation, use inline styles, or add styles to a global stylesheet depending on your use case.

A component's styles are scoped to the component by default. Angular achieves this by adding an attribute to elements in the component's scope and by changing the selectors in the styles to require this attribute.
You can see this in the result of rendering your component (where _ngcontent-ng-c2626609219 is the attribute that's been inserted):
<div _ngcontent-ng-c2626609219="">
  <div _ngcontent-ng-c2626609219="" class="target">Pre-existing .target element</div>
  <div class="target">Dynamic .target element</div>
</div>

This means that your .target selector was converted to something like .target[_ngcontent-ng-c2626609219] which is why your new element does not have the expected styling - the selector doesn't match the new element because it does not have this attribute.
There are two ways to fix this behavior:

Use Renderer2.createElement() instead of document.createElement().

import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, inject, Renderer2, viewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div #container>
      <div class="target">Pre-existing .target element</div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: `
    .target {
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
  `,
})
export class FooComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  private readonly renderer2 = inject(Renderer2);
  private readonly container = viewChild.required<ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>>('container');

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.container().nativeElement) {
      const target = this.renderer2.createElement('div');
      target.innerText = 'Dynamic .target element';
      target.classList.add('target');
      this.container().nativeElement.appendChild(target);
    }
  }
}


The dynamic element now also has the attribute and so now also matches the modified selector.
<div _ngcontent-ng-c2626609219="">
  <div _ngcontent-ng-c2626609219="" class="target">Pre-existing .target element</div>
  <div _ngcontent-ng-c2626609219="" class="target">Dynamic .target element</div>
</div>

You can use the other methods on Renderer2 as well, but they're not necessary in this case:
ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.container().nativeElement) {
    const target = this.renderer2.createElement('div');
    const text = this.renderer2.createText('Dynamic .target element');
    this.renderer2.appendChild(target, text);
    this.renderer2.addClass(target, 'target');
    this.renderer2.appendChild(this.container().nativeElement, target);
  }
}


Change the way Angular scopes the component's styles by setting encapsulation to ViewEncapsulation.None:

import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div #container>
      <div class="target">Pre-existing .target element</div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: `
    .target {
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class FooComponent { 
  // ...
}

The result of rendering your component now lacks the custom attribute and the .target selector has not been changed to use the attribute:
<div>
  <div class="target">Pre-existing .target element</div>
  <div class="target">Dynamic .target element</div>
</div>

You have to be careful with this approach because the .target style may now match other elements you're not intending for it to match.

Here are some common reasons why styles might not apply to dynamically inserted elements

View Encapsulation

Angular applies view encapsulation by default, meaning styles are scoped to each component by appending unique attribute selectors to elements.
If you dynamically insert an element outside of the component’s encapsulated scope, its styles may not apply, as Angular’s encapsulation will not extend to these new elements.
Solution: Try setting encapsulation to ViewEncapsulation.None in your component to disable style encapsulation, which makes styles global within the application.
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // Makes styles global
})
export class ExampleComponent { }


Using Renderer2 for Dynamic Element Creation

When dynamically creating elements using Angular’s Renderer2, the styles may not apply if the elements are not within the component's view hierarchy.
Renderer2 will insert elements into the DOM, but they may not inherit the scoped component styles if they’re not within the encapsulated template structure.
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elRef: ElementRef) { }
ngOnInit() {
  const newDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div');
  this.renderer.setStyle(newDiv, 'color', 'red'); // Apply inline styles
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.elRef.nativeElement, newDiv);
}


Scoped Styles and Shadow DOM (if using ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom)

Ensure that any dynamic elements you create are added within the component template itself.For Shadow DOM, you can’t bypass encapsulation without inline styles or ViewEncapsulation.None.

CSS Specificity Issues

If the dynamically inserted element has existing styles with higher specificity (e.g., from a global stylesheet or third-party library), it can override the component’s styles.
Solution:
Increase specificity by adding classes directly to dynamic elements using Renderer2
